# Flutter VLC rtsp reconnect to stream

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to make VLC in flutter to automatically attempt to reconnect to a rtsp stream if the connection fails or I can set up a refresh button to reconnect again?

I've tried re-initializing the VLC controller by `VlcPlayerController.network()` and refreshing the widget with `setState((){})` but it doesn't do anything. The only way I can think of is by closing/disposing the widget and create a new one.